# How do I POST data to a .NET Core Web API using the fetch() javascript method

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, asp.net-core, fetch

I am attempting to POST data from a React front end to a .NET Core Web API method. I am POSTing using the `fetch()` javascript method. When I set a breakpoint in the .NET code to analyze the values of the viewModel, all its members are null.

I've also tried passing a simple string instead of the view model, but that is also null.

I've tried adding the `[FromBody]` attribute in front of the parameter.

ContactForm.js

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        viewModel: {
            name: this.state.name,
            serviceRequested: this.state.interest,
            email: this.state.email,
            phone: this.state.phone,
            contactPreference: this.state.preference
        }
    };

    fetch('api/Contact/Contact', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)      
    })
    .then(response => {
        response.text().then(function (text) {
            alert(text);
        });
    });

}
```

ContactController.cs

```cs
private readonly string successMessage = "success";
private readonly string modelStateMessage = "Invalid input.";

[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            return Content(modelStateMessage);
        }

        return Content(successMessage);
    }
```

ContactFormViewModel.cs

```cs
public class ContactFormViewModel {

    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string ServiceRequested {get; set;}

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone {get;set;}

    public string ContactPreference {get;set;}

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Message {get;set;}

}
```

I am expecting the data to populate the view models properties, but they are all null. Firefox's dev tools show the Request is passing JSON params in the body.

Comment: As you say yourself, in the request body is your data. The JavaScript is fine. I would suggest changing the question title, this seems not related to fetch. Have you tried posting something with postman for example?

Comment: I mostly work in .NET Framework, so this may not apply to Core, but normally when I have a POST function it accepts `FormCollection collection` as its parameters, rather than the view model. Maybe give this a try: `public ActionResult Contact(FormCollection collection)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code from :

```
let data = {
    viewModel: {
        name: this.state.name,
        serviceRequested: this.state.interest,
        email: this.state.email,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        contactPreference: this.state.preference
    }
};
```

To :

```
let data = {                    
    name: this.state.name,
    serviceRequested: this.state.interest,
    email: this.state.email,
    phone: this.state.phone,
    contactPreference: this.state.preference
};
```

And keep your client code to post json string with `application/json` as content-type . Receive the value on server side with `[FromBody]` :

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ActionResult Contact([FromBody]ContactFormViewModel viewModel)
{

   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing viewModel: {...} worked. So, I wonder what it would look like if I had two view models? Will play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use to make the method as static and async, you can modify accordingly i.e. remove static and async in case you don't need..If you have any query please reply

Below is code:

```
  static async post(URL, body) {
    debugger;
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL_PREFIX}/api/${url}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
    })

    return response.ok;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into making it async. I've also seen some examples using fetch with async.